# Как реализовать продажу офлайн курсов на WP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт, нужно реализовать продажу музыкальных курсов .
Пример:

1. Незарегистрированный клиент заходит на сайт - выбирает курс, нажимает кнопку "Оплатить курс", его перебрасывает на страницу регистрации, он регистририруется, после этого его логинит, и  кидает на страницу личного кабинета, где он видит тот курс , который он выбрал прежде со статусом - "не оплачен". Потом ему звонит администратор этого заведения, уточняет все детали, даёт реквизиты на оплату, он оплачивает, пока идёт подтверждение оплаты - статус его курса - "на утверждении". Как только администратор получит оплату, статус курса он меняет в админке на "Оплачен", и дальше там уточняет с клиентом информацию.

2. Зарегистрированный клиент выбирает курс, и дальше процесс тот же - его кидает на страницу личного кабинета, где этот курс уже есть со статусом "не оплачен" ....

3. Администратор должен в админке видеть все курсы, и всех клиентов , которые подписались на курсы, а так же у него должна быть возможность менять статус этих курсов.

4. После регистрации, что админу, что клиенту должно приходить письмо на почту об информации, а так же после каждого изменения статуса заказа письмо на почту.

Курсов планируется не больше 15. Так что WooCommerce не вариант.

Пытался реализовать это с помощью плагинов-магазинов, не получилось.
Внизу список плагинов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же пробовал пойти в сторону LMS на WP- тоже не вышло.
Внизу список плагинов из данной категории:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал может быть сделать с помощью кастомного типа поста, но тогда вопрос - как это всё показывать клиенту, а так же админу...
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать ?
Ума не приложу.

Comment: Кроме WC есть ещё масса других плагинов ИМ. (и стоило писать такую простыню для ИМ цифровых товаров..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуй memberluxe плагин, из того что ты описываешь, с подобным набором наврядли найдешь по функционалу плагины. Если отдельно кодера нанимать.

Comment: спасибо, но он платный, а денег у меня нет(

Comment: я сам разработчик, но начинающий, думал может кто подскажет в какую сторону смотреть, и с чего начать.

Comment: Не стоит изобретать велосипед, в сети валом добра, испытай для начала, если подойдет по функционалу, думай в сторону лицензии. Еще есть aMemberPro. Там валом функций, самый богатый на сколько мне известно по функционалу скрипт.